# Can't open an image in CS63 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, proj

I have an image in projection [Pulkovo 1942 / CS63 zone X2](http://georepository.com/crs_7826/Pulkovo-1942-CS63-zone-X2.html). When I try to open it in QGIS, it fails to detect the projection and asks to select the projection manually. Does QGIS handle this family of projections?

```
$ gdalsrsinfo '/home/user/Downloads/2DJI_0983.tif'

PROJ.4 : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0833333333333333 +lon_0=26.5 +k=1 +x_0=2300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.92,-141.27,-80.9,0,0.35,0.82,-0.12 +units=m +no_defs

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["Pulkovo 1942 / CS63 zone X2",
    GEOGCS["Pulkovo 1942",
        DATUM["Pulkovo_1942",
            SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245,298.2999999999998,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6284"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4284"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.0833333333333333],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",26.5],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",2300000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","7826"]]
```

Also I managed to reproject the image into EPSG:4326 using gdalwarp, but I'm not sure whether the reprojection went right. Do GDAL and PROJ work correctly with this projection? Maybe there is an open source software using which I could open the image to assure the reprojection accuracy?

QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas, GDAL 2.1.0, PROJ 4.8.0

Comment: QGIS 3.0.3 has EPSG:7826 in the CRS list. Is it missing from your 2.18? You can open the image that you projected into EPSG:4326 with QGIS and add some other raster or vector data from the same area and see if they match.

Comment: QGIS 2.18 was released within a few months of this CRS being added to EPSG in July. QGIS / GDAL / Proj possiblyupdateed the EPSG files before that. GDAL 2.1 was released in May; Proj 4.8.0 in 2012.

Comment: @user30184, yes, there's no EPSG:7826 in my build of QGIS

Comment: @mkennedy, thank you. I believe I have to update the libraries to make it work with EPSG:7826